# Drive failed to mount

Tags: macbook-pro

A few days ago I left an external hard drive connected to my MacBook. The MacBook's battery drained and therefore the drive was "not properly disconnected". Ever since I can't have access to my drive anymore. I've been trying to mount it or verify it with Terminal, but I haven't managed to succeed.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
#: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER
0: FDisk_partition_scheme *256.1 GB disk2
1: 0xEF 74.0 MB disk2s1

diskutil verifydisk disk2
Unable to verify this whole disk: A GUID Partition Table (GPT) partitioning scheme is required (-69773)

diskutil verifyVolume disk2s1
Error starting file system verification for disk2s1: Unrecognized file system (-69846)

diskutil mount disk2s1
Volume on disk2s1 failed to mount
Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported)
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option

diskutil mount readOnly disk2s1
Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported)
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

In Single User, I used `sbin/fsck_exfat /dev/disk2`, but I had no luck.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 count=3 | hexdump -Cv
Password:
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
1536 bytes transferred in 0.002198 secs (698823 bytes/sec)
00000000  33 c0 8e d0 bc 00 7c fb  8e d8 8e c0 fc 66 89 0e  |3.....|......f..|
00000010  f0 04 66 89 36 f4 04 66  c7 06 f8 04 00 00 00 00  |..f.6..f........|
00000020  66 c7 06 fc 04 00 00 00  00 be 37 7c bf 37 06 50  |f.........7|.7.P|
00000030  57 b9 c9 01 f3 a4 cb e8  02 01 20 50 6c 65 61 73  |W......... Pleas|
00000040  65 20 77 61 69 74 2e 2e  2e 00 bf be 07 f6 05 80  |e wait..........|
00000050  75 6e 83 c7 10 81 ff fe  07 72 f2 e8 de 00 4d 69  |un.......r....Mi|
00000060  73 73 69 6e 67 20 6f 70  65 72 61 74 69 6e 67 20  |ssing operating |
00000070  73 79 73 74 65 6d 00 eb  fe e8 c0 00 45 72 72 6f  |system......Erro|
00000080  72 20 6c 6f 61 64 69 6e  67 20 6f 70 65 72 61 74  |r loading operat|
00000090  69 6e 67 20 73 79 73 74  65 6d 00 eb fe e8 9c 00  |ing system......|
000000a0  49 6e 76 61 6c 69 64 20  70 61 72 74 69 74 69 6f  |Invalid partitio|
000000b0  6e 20 74 61 62 6c 65 20  65 6e 74 72 79 00 eb fe  |n table entry...|
000000c0  e8 2f 00 72 b4 81 3e fe  7d 55 aa 75 d0 e8 b1 00  |./.r..>.}U.u....|
000000d0  75 15 b0 d1 e6 64 e8 a8  00 b0 df e6 60 e8 a1 00  |u....d......`...|
000000e0  b0 ff e6 64 e8 9a 00 bf  00 7c e8 57 00 ea 00 7c  |...d.....|.W...||
000000f0  00 00 bb aa 55 b4 41 cd  13 72 1b 81 fb 55 aa 75  |....U.A..r...U.u|
00000100  15 f6 c1 01 74 10 66 8b  45 08 66 a3 2e 07 be 26  |....t.f.E.f....&|
00000110  07 b4 42 cd 13 c3 b8 01  02 bb 00 7c 8b 4d 02 8a  |..B........|.M..|
00000120  75 01 cd 13 c3 90 10 00  01 00 00 7c 00 00 00 00  |u..........|....|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 33 db  b4 0e cd 10 5e ac 56 3c  |......3.....^.V<|
00000140  00 75 f3 c3 60 b8 00 bb  cd 1a 72 32 66 23 c0 75  |.u..`.....r2f#.u|
00000150  2d 66 81 fb 54 43 50 41  75 24 61 60 66 bb 54 43  |-f..TCPAu$a`f.TC|
00000160  50 41 66 be 0c 00 00 00  66 b9 00 02 00 00 66 ba  |PAf.....f.....f.|
00000170  04 00 00 00 b8 07 bb cd  1a 83 f8 00 74 01 f9 61  |............t..a|
00000180  c3 33 c9 e4 64 eb 00 24  02 e0 f8 24 02 c3 00 00  |.3..d..$...$....|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  fe 68 98 e1 00 00 80 01  |.........h......|
000001c0  01 00 ef f8 01 02 3f 00  00 00 8a 34 02 00 00 00  |......?....4....|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200  fa 5c 4c 76 bb 34 8e ef  c6 dc 80 0c 50 bd c8 e8  |.\Lv.4......P...|
00000210  c3 1a 34 3b ac c3 dd bf  88 d9 7b 2e 1f 72 46 d7  |..4;......{..rF.|
00000220  bc a9 66 2f a9 ea 3f 8b  ac f7 5e 91 39 af 49 9e  |..f/..?...^.9.I.|
00000230  21 dc 71 41 4e 1c b6 3a  9f ea 90 3e 09 c2 1b 7e  |!.qAN..:...>...~|
00000240  76 0d 2e 4b 97 ae 41 f5  ac 46 cc 3f 36 3b 4e 05  |v..K..A..F.?6;N.|
00000250  62 31 93 da 6e 62 da 7e  8b d6 b9 51 b6 cb 28 03  |b1..nb.~...Q..(.|
00000260  aa a2 7f f3 f8 01 7a ad  b7 64 f3 69 cf 72 67 e1  |......z..d.i.rg.|
00000270  a6 d1 df fc 2c c8 e4 be  68 ac c7 84 25 e7 c3 ec  |....,...h...%...|
00000280  62 0d 5c 0f 0e ba 5a 21  7f 1e d0 b6 9b b1 e8 4f  |b.\...Z!.......O|
00000290  c7 98 53 5e 51 90 a2 39  19 7b bc 58 61 af 52 5f  |..S^Q..9.{.Xa.R_|
000002a0  80 b7 02 9c 03 a9 8d e2  01 f3 7a 55 4d f1 6b e0  |..........zUM.k.|
000002b0  05 c4 f8 83 7a 14 8d 72  b5 a0 c0 c1 74 fd 3c aa  |....z..r....t.<.|
000002c0  5f 46 69 3e 79 a5 68 0e  87 aa ba 00 9b a0 13 38  |_Fi>y.h........8|
000002d0  f7 18 dc 74 e1 fb 56 16  82 08 af d5 1c 0e 86 fe  |...t..V.........|
000002e0  12 c3 15 36 77 2d b4 e4  93 2d 16 45 80 47 c2 fd  |...6w-...-.E.G..|
000002f0  bf fb 2a ea 4a 76 0a 34  8c 21 ec 9a 1f 61 14 7e  |..*.Jv.4.!...a.~|
00000300  8e 56 d7 09 33 8c f3 55  47 b3 0c 4b c7 1c 09 fe  |.V..3..UG..K....|
00000310  22 8a 8e ed ae bb 51 db  90 01 0e ab 20 4f 0f 19  |".....Q..... O..|
00000320  d7 3e ba 1e d0 ef da 43  63 e8 69 8b 54 51 32 1b  |.>.....Cc.i.TQ2.|
00000330  17 d4 26 7d c8 0a 3b 45  cc d5 3a cc c9 c5 19 4a  |..&}..;E..:....J|
00000340  9a c6 c1 01 d2 11 96 7f  a8 7f 64 a9 bb d0 67 c8  |..........d...g.|
00000350  d9 5b 03 27 1f 27 a9 29  b7 fc 09 ea 11 df 5f 48  |.[.'.'.)......_H|
00000360  5e 42 4e 1e 37 91 83 45  b2 c5 15 70 62 38 68 86  |^BN.7..E...pb8h.|
00000370  e3 58 3b 26 4f 8a 2d 7f  2b cd a3 70 1c 9f 59 60  |.X;&O.-.+..p..Y`|
00000380  b4 e1 a3 42 c0 26 70 0e  60 97 f7 7d fa 18 6f 1b  |...B.&p.`..}..o.|
00000390  27 6d ee 7c 91 c3 3e 49  5b dd 64 4a c4 dd b3 e3  |'m.|..>I[.dJ....|
000003a0  5e 4b b6 ed 45 6b 30 c3  3b fd a0 0b ff 6b 6f 9c  |^K..Ek0.;....ko.|
000003b0  c6 41 df f6 a3 20 c0 1a  bf 03 02 8e 35 8a 4c b8  |.A... ......5.L.|
000003c0  dc a6 fa 9b 1d 36 46 8b  72 f9 c9 2c e5 5b 50 e4  |.....6F.r..,.[P.|
000003d0  e8 65 d2 bb 04 54 b1 d5  0c 5a d6 26 1d 31 ba a7  |.e...T...Z.&.1..|
000003e0  f3 bc 44 b7 89 6e 35 fe  be 57 9a 34 4b 42 2d f2  |..D..n5..W.4KB-.|
000003f0  9a 11 b7 7c c8 cd 8a b8  c3 12 8e 98 77 27 b6 4b  |...|........w'.K|
00000400  c0 88 06 e4 a4 72 21 01  ea 15 4e 3d 9a c3 1d f8  |.....r!...N=....|
00000410  a9 5f 83 b2 15 29 65 99  e6 3e e7 8b 82 24 43 cc  |._...)e..>...$C.|
00000420  7f 62 3e 37 a7 82 15 b5  be 56 39 54 91 93 bf bb  |.b>7.....V9T....|
00000430  8a 0c 10 3f 70 b6 bc df  7e 5e d3 61 89 6d b3 70  |...?p...~^.a.m.p|
00000440  64 a9 f9 7b 2d e3 a6 08  4c c0 59 62 a7 89 2b ad  |d..{-...L.Yb..+.|
00000450  0b b4 e3 c0 ff 1a 07 97  5c fd af 4e e3 b9 43 94  |........\..N..C.|
00000460  e2 a6 94 3b df 2a 1e 2f  c8 cf 6c 95 4a f7 6c 3b  |...;.*./..l.J.l;|
00000470  0a a4 7d b5 cb 42 a4 a3  f8 55 a8 cf 88 bc 74 0a  |..}..B...U....t.|
00000480  4a fc ab 7d 9b 8c 27 fd  54 ed 52 b0 8b 13 7a ac  |J..}..'.T.R...z.|
00000490  3f 49 bf 56 8a 68 43 4d  c5 39 3a 19 57 f1 29 55  |?I.V.hCM.9:.W.)U|
000004a0  57 27 e7 ce db 19 ab 4b  d3 fd d0 e1 c5 06 76 11  |W'.....K......v.|
000004b0  f9 70 53 7c b6 5e a8 24  75 c8 68 ac 8d cb d3 7d  |.pS|.^.$u.h....}|
000004c0  30 f5 02 23 c3 cb 75 4f  10 9a 30 cb aa f7 d1 90  |0..#..uO..0.....|
000004d0  b0 f0 de 92 53 36 02 6c  ab 78 78 20 9c 6a c6 fe  |....S6.l.xx .j..|
000004e0  e6 a3 2b e3 30 c7 ba 2c  7a e9 3f c9 ff 56 70 5a  |..+.0..,z.?..VpZ|
000004f0  61 da c9 fc 52 fa 8a bb  ab 74 68 ca 18 57 54 be  |a...R....th..WT.|
00000500  b2 82 c0 af bf f9 72 28  fe 53 9a a4 3d 4d 8e 8a  |......r(.S..=M..|
00000510  ba 4a cb 5d 3e 95 e5 8e  1c 0a 55 6c 60 3d d7 54  |.J.]>.....Ul`=.T|
00000520  47 02 30 5e 2a 00 a8 d3  b4 f5 fc 43 1a 79 48 72  |G.0^*......C.yHr|
00000530  af ce e1 65 6a 84 db 1f  07 cd 83 ce d7 8e e8 38  |...ej..........8|
00000540  f1 64 71 2f e5 1d fc 46  0f 91 6d 38 c3 4b 00 a5  |.dq/...F..m8.K..|
00000550  96 15 8e 78 30 a2 c7 2e  48 79 6a 71 7b b7 37 00  |...x0...Hyjq{.7.|
00000560  6e 3e d4 21 6f 5c 57 96  96 51 90 29 f6 17 bd 0f  |n>.!o\W..Q.)....|
00000570  c7 4d 77 2e 79 16 7f 5f  3f 52 a4 7c d5 21 22 46  |.Mw.y.._?R.|.!"F|
00000580  76 38 29 06 d4 32 1f d4  63 d6 48 a4 71 bb 76 2f  |v8)..2..c.H.q.v/|
00000590  80 4c 08 de 34 4e 00 26  a5 99 1d 28 9f 75 11 a8  |.L..4N.&...(.u..|
000005a0  91 0b 9b 60 ed 43 9d 0e  f0 af 5a 0d d4 f1 9e d3  |...`.C....Z.....|
000005b0  94 d5 49 94 98 07 2b 7a  5a 21 b6 49 79 57 fd eb  |..I...+zZ!.IyW..|
000005c0  5d 5e 75 77 3f 42 90 79  db 69 06 dd e0 fb 06 d5  |]^uw?B.y.i......|
000005d0  93 17 f9 3c 6b a9 6d 96  8a db 8a d6 eb 7d fd 82  |...<k.m......}..|
000005e0  94 3c 1d 18 1b f8 be a9  e1 ad c3 ec 8a 1c 83 b9  |.<..............|
000005f0  1d 91 ad 98 51 8b 71 12  02 5a f5 9e 5d a3 fe b6  |....Q.q..Z..]...|
00000600
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could edit your question and add the output from the command `sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 count=3 | hexdump -Cv`. Also, can you state what file systems were on the drive. Was macOS installed on the drive?

Comment: MacOS was installed on the drive

Comment: @Salif: I would appear the partition table data at the beginning of the disk has been corrupted. Can I assume you just want to erase the disk and reinstall macOS or something else?

Comment: It may be due to a few command lines taken from some website that I used to try to mount the disk. But all I want is to erase the disk and reinstall it

Comment: What prevents you from using Disk Utility to format the disk?

Comment: I tried but the disc does not mount. I don't think there is a problem with a partition

Comment: you can erase it from Disk Utility

Comment: How? Because I tried several times and it didn't work. It takes forever and remains frozen.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to my problem. Should I conclude that the drive is dead